# Android - AppCompatEditText theme doesn't get applied inside of fragment

Tags: android, themes, fragment, android-appcompat

I've added the new app-compat library *'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.0'* to my project, but it seems to have a problem to apply a theme to the AppCompatEditText, when it's inside of a fragment.

This is my EditText:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="@color/teal_300"
        android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
        android:textColorHint="@color/text_hint"
        style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display1"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MyTheme.EditText"/>
```

This is the theme:

```
<style name="Theme.MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/teal_500</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/teal_700</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/orange_500</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/grey</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/teal_300</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/teal_300</item>
    <item name="colorSwitchThumbNormal">@color/teal_300</item>
</style>

<style name="Theme.MyTheme.EditText" parent="Theme.MyTheme">
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/orange_500</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/orange_500</item>
</style>
```

So basically I just want to change the color of the underline of the EditText to orange instead of grey/teal.

When I put this code directly inside the layout of an activity it works just fine, so the underline is orange. But if I put the same code inside the layout of a fragment, the underline is grey/teal. So the theme doesn't seem to get applied.

Thanks

Comment: You do not use `AppCompatEditText` directly. Just use `EditText` and the `LayoutInflater` provided by `AppCompatActivity` inflates `AppCompatEditText` instead automatically. The same goes for other widgets.

Comment: Okay, when I change it to normal EditText the colors get applied, but it doesn't look like the material EditText anymore. So it doesn't has just this straight underline, but it also has this little edges on the left and right. Idk which is worse :)

Comment: `@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display1` belongs in `android:textAppearance` not `style` attribute. This might actually fix it.

Comment: nope, unfortunately the same result as above

Comment: Can you post your `Fragment.onCreateView` method? And how you add the fragment to the activity? Add it at the end of your question please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a problem introducced on 22.1

The problem comes when you use the inflater instance passed to Fragment#onCreateView().

The workaround for now is to instead used the LayoutInflater from getActivity().getLayoutInflater().

Comment: yep, that did the trick, thanks! 
could there be a drawback to get the inflater like this?

Comment: According to Google it will be fixed within a week. Here's a link to the issue https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=169760

Comment: @EkKoZ i'm still facing this problem on 22.2.0

Answer (score 0):

You should use a style instead of the theme for the EditText like:

```
<style name="EditText" parent="Widget.AppCompat.EditText">
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/orange_500</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/orange_500</item>
     <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display1</item>
</style>
```

Than apply just the style and no theme.

Comment: If anything a custom `EditText` style should inherit from `Widget.AppCompat.EditText`. Please do not mix text appearance and widget styles.

Comment: thanks, but that code doesn't work neither in the fragment nor in the activity